# Confusion about orientations in Greens second identity

Tags: differential-geometry

This question has been the source of some confusion on my part so I am hoping there is someone out there who can clear it up.

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f,g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{C})$. It is trivial to check that
$$ d\Big( g\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dy  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dx\Big) -  f\Big( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dy  - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dx\Big)\Big) = (g\Delta^e f - f\Delta^e g ) dxdy, $$
where $$ \Delta^e = \partial_x^2 +\partial_y^2.$$
Using Stokes theorem this identity clearly leads to Greens second identity
$$ \int_{\partial \Omega} \Big( g\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dy  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dx\Big) -  f\Big( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dy  - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dx\Big)\Big) = \int_{\Omega} (g\Delta^e f - f\Delta^e g ) dxdy, $$
however I am a bit confused as to the orientation of $\partial \Omega$. Going back to the definitions and unpacking everything it seems to me that the orientation should be counter-clockwise (which also fit with the elementary version of Greens theorem), but a number of authors (most notably Daniel Bump in "Automorphic forms and Representations" p. 133) seem to claim that the orientation should be taken clockwise. Is there some subtelety in play here that I am overlooking with regards to the orientation of $\mathbb{C}$?

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: Orientation is only a choice but most of the standard text books choose "counter-clockwise" as "positive".

Comment: However if the orientation of the surface is chosen, the induced orientation of its boundary is determined, by the "right hand rule"

Comment: True. In particular, if the area is oriented as $dx\wedge dy$, its boundary has to be oriented counter-clockwise.